# How to merge multiple csv files into single dataset using SAS

Tags: sas

I have ~2300 CSV files and colunm 1 variable name is different for each CSV file. I want to merge all files by panelistID (colunm 2) and run frequencies on column 1 to get frequency of each CSV file. Please can someone help?

Below example of file layout:

```
File1

mat1_pen1, panelistID

0,  10075001

20, 10086001

44, 10086002

10, 10096001

File2

mat2_pen2, panelistID

74, 10118002

40, 10118003

77, 10128001

77, 10128003


file 3

mat3_pen4, panelistID

77, 10128003

51, 10137001

0,  10148001

0,  10148002

0,  10157001
```

Comment: Can you post any code you've already tried or explain what you've already attempted?  That will help other people answer your question.

Comment: Can I vote for "get the person who thought it was a good idea to give you 2300 CSV files fired"?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use a wildcard on the `infile` statement to read in all the files, and the `filename=` option to store the current file in a temporary variable `_f`, storing it into `f`.

Then manipulate `f` and `var` accordingly.

```
data big ;
  length _f f $256. ;
  infile "*.csv" truncover filename=_f dlm=',' ;
  f = _f ;
  input var
        panellistID
        ;
run ;
```

Comment: The problem is, the way I read the question, he wanted to maintain the original variable names listed in the column headers; this solution keeps them all in the same column.  And mixes character and numeric data with the column headers.  Both problems can be solved with some transposing, conversion etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename mycsv "*.csv";

data mydataset(drop=tmp);
   infile mycsv dsd dlm=',' eov=eov;
   retain mat_pen_id;

   if _n_ = 1  or eov then do;        *when using wildcard-concatenated input files, ;
      input mat_pen_id $20. tmp $20.;    *eov is true for first line of second file.; 
      eov = 0;
    else do;                          * _n_ =1 is true for first line of first file only;
        input mat_pen panelistID;
   end;
run;

proc sort data= mydataset;
   by panelistID;
run;

proc transpose
  data=mydataset out=wide_data;
      by panelistID;
      id mat_pen_id;
      var mat_pen;
      run;

proc print data=wide_data;
run;
```

This will give you a dataset called wide_data like:

```
obs   panelistID mat1_pen1 mat2_pen2 mat3_pen3 etc

1      10075001     0        22            33
```