# Read in Files with pattern match into one SAS dataset

Tags: sas

I would like to read a number of .csv files into a single SAS dataset using a pattern match. For example if in the directory `/home/datasets` there are 5 files:

```
/home/datasets
   ~/output_group1a.csv
   ~/output_group1b.csv
   ~/output_group1c.csv
   ~/output_group2a.csv
   ~/output_group2b.csv
```

All with known and identical structures and data types. I would like to read in only those files corresponding to group 1 without having to explicitly specify the filenames.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple csv files into single dataset using SAS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737237/how-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-into-single-dataset-using-sas)

Comment: @RobertPenridge I do not want them merged, I would like the files stacked

Comment: It's just a poor choice of words in the title... The linked question does answer your question.

Comment: I think it's a duplicate, but I also don't like the answers for that one as much as the answer below - this one handles things like 1st obs.

Comment: Actually, @RobertPenridge, that question *does* want to merge (side by side, not set) the data - note that it has an ID variable and a _Different_ second variable for each file.

Comment: Ahh, you are right again Joe.  Apologies mkemp6 - I was looking at the answer in the post that I linked to more than the question...  Yeah I found 4 similar questions and picked that one based on the most voted answer...  @Reeza's answer is much nicer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a wildcard in your infile statement. If you have headers in each file you'll need to account for that. Here's a bit more of an example.

https://gist.github.com/statgeek/4c27ea9a7ed6d3528835

```
data try01;

length filename txt_file_name $256;

retain txt_file_name;

infile "Path\*.txt" eov=eov filename=filename truncover;

input@;

if _n_ eq 1 or eov then do;

txt_file_name = scan(filename, -2, ".\");

eov=0;

end;

else input

 *Place input code here;

;



run;
```