# SAS: Using macro to import multiple text files

Tags: sas

I am using SAS to import hundreds of csv files.

There are 300 city data-sets with the following naming convention (**Shanghai001-Shanghai100, London001-London100, Newyork001-Newyork100**).

My current import code is

```
data shanghai001;
  infile 'H:\shanghai001.csv'
  delimiter = ',' DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;

  informat Date_L_ DATE11.;
  informat Time_L_ time18.3;
  informat Type $10.;

  format Date_L_ DATE11.;
  format Time_L_ time18.3;
  format Type $10.;

  input
  Date_L_
  Time_L_
  Type  $
  ;                                         
run;
```

This code works, but I just want to know how to use **`macro`** to import these 300 data sets?

Any smart guy can tell me ?

Comment: I think you mean macro. I'm not a guy so won't answer either.

Comment: Wait, if the code works, why can't you import the 300 data sets?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a macro to do this, but you do not need to.  It would probably be much easier to read all of the CSV files into a single data set.  You could add variables like FNAME and VERSION to tell which observations came from which source file.

```
data all_data;
  length fname $100 path $200 version 8 ;
  length Date_L_ Time_L_ 8 Type $10.;
  informat Date_L_ date11. Time_L_ time18.3 ;
  format version z3. Date_L_ date11. Time_L_ time12.3 ;
  do fname='shanghai','london','newyork';
    do version=1 to 100 ;
      path = catx('\','H:',cats(fname,put(version,z3.),'.csv'));
      if not fileexist(path) then do;
         put 'ERROR: File not found. ' path=:$quote.;
         continue;
      end;
      infile csvfile filevar=path dsd truncover end=eof;
      if not eof then input ;
      do while (not eof);
        input Date_L_ Time_L_ Type ;
        output;
      end;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Tom's answer answer's the specific question.  But for a more general way of doing this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737237/how-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-into-single-dataset-using-sas/17744543#17744543